# Swift Playground Ipad Saving input data and restore when needed

Tags: ipad

Below codes works on **Ipad** playground, but I want to save input data and later retrieve it. For example the following inputs:

```
     let xGuardtar = askForNumber()
     let irpf = askForDecimal()
     let brutox = bruto as NSNumber
```

The other problem is that it should be placed at the end of the code, but what to do, when i would like to retrieve it when the app is opened, and a file exists!!, it will wait until all inputs are gathered again....ps don’t want to use a button.

Looked everywhere but found nothing....thanks in advance (> swift 4)

Code that works:

```
// Additional save data
struct Note: Codable {
    let title: String
    let text: String
    let timestamp: Date
}
let note1 = Note(title: "Note One", text: "This is a sample note.",     timestamp: Date())
let note2 = Note(title: "Note Two", text: "This is another sample note.",     timestamp: Date())
let note3 = Note(title: "Note Three", text: "This is yet another sample     note.", timestamp: Date())
let notes = [note1, note2, note3]

let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for:     .documentDirectory,in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let archiveURL =         documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("notes_test").appendingPathExten.   .   sion("plist")
    let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
    let encodedNotes = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(notes)
    try? encodedNotes?.write(to: archiveURL,options: .noFileProtection)

//  Comments retrieve data
let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()
if let retrievedNotesData = try? Data(contentsOf: archiveURL),
    let decodedNotes = try?
        propertyListDecoder.decode(Array<Note>.self, from:
            retrievedNotesData) {
    print(decodedNotes)
}
```

Comment: let data = [Brutox,Irpf,xGuardtar, ] as [Any].                                              This seems to work, still to save and recal if file exists...almost there...

Comment: Strange that this works, inorder to muliply int with double.....need to convert etc etc...